# C++ regular expression sscanf

Tags: c++, expression, scanf

I wanto to use sscanf to extrat the 2 first integer (5 and 10) in a string
rssi = 5
ber = 10
like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  std::string  str = "\r\n+CSQ: 5,10\r\n\r\nOK\r\n7556\r\n";
  unsigned char lBufRX[100];
  char *rssi, *ber;

  if((sscanf(str.c_str(), "%*[^:]: %s,%s[^\n]", rssi, ber)) != 2) {
    std::cout <<"[" << rssi << "]" << "[" << ber << "]"  << std::endl;
  } 
  
  return 0;
}
```

The result is bad. Can anyone help me ?

My output is : "[5,10][" with " %*[^:]: " i read until the first integer so "5" with ",%s[^\n]" i read the second integer so "10" until \r\n

Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific about your program's output.  _"The result is bad"_ does not describe anything meaningful.  However, I _can_ see that you are reading strings into uninitialized pointers.  That means an unspecified memory location that your program almost certainly has no authority to write to.  And that would be... "bad".

Comment: My output is : 
"[5,10]["

with " %*[^:]: "  i read until the first integer so "5"
with ",%s[^\n]"  i read the second integer so "10" until \r\n

Comment: Yep, that looks like a possible output, as is almost any other output because your program's behavior is undefined.

Comment: You have to allocate memory for `rssi` and `ber`

Comment: Or... why not just make `rssi` and `ber` integers and read into them using `%d`?  Isn't that what you're after anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors. You're using `char*` although you want to read two `int`s. But then you don't allocate memory for them. Also, you're expecting two successful parses but check with `!= 2`. Here is some code that works:

```cpp
int main() {

  std::string  str = "\r\n+CSQ: 5,10\r\n\r\nOK\r\n7556\r\n";
  int rssi, ber;

  if((sscanf(str.c_str(), "%*[^:]: %d,%d", &rssi, &ber)) == 2) {
    std::cout <<"[" << rssi << "]" << "[" << ber << "]"  << std::endl;
  } 
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right. That part can be skipped. I just modified the original code to a form that works without thinking about optimizing it. But that can be removed.